# How do I interpret this Weibull plot?

Tags: r, distributions, modeling, data-mining

I was exploring Weibull analysis for understanding reliability of two specific specimen. I used the R package, "[weibulltoolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/weibulltoolkit/)" and "[survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html)" to get the plot in question. The dataset is big so I am not posting it.

```
X = read.table("./test", header=T)
d <- data.frame(ob=X, state=1)
s = Surv(d$ob, d$state)
plot.wb(s)
```

From my understanding, both plots indicate bad fits! This could be an artifact of having too many data-points in the system or could be due to seasonal-effects or other unknown effects. Looking at the plot, what am I supposed to understand? Specifically,

- Plot 1 (using 4000 points) seems to indicate the presence of two different behaviors (0.05 - 5 and 5-1e+05). Does this mean that I am better off splitting the dataset into two and analyzing them separately? If so, what is the implication of this?
- Same seems to be going for Plot 2 (using 400 points) i.e. I would be better of splitting this dataset as well.

What is a good way of comparing these two datasets? Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Upon Googling, I came across something called Multiple failure modes though I am not sure how to do this in R. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

#### PLOT 1

[image]

#### PLOT 2

[image]

Comment: What is your goal? Do you  really need Weibull, or any other parametric analysis? The `survival` package has loads of nonparametric methods.

Comment: Well, my goal is to compare the reliability of these two specimen. If there is a better way to do this, please feel free to suggest. It is just that I came across Weibull yesterday and thought of playing around with it.

Comment: @Brandon Bertelsen: Done! Hope it looks better now :)